# Sort Shopify Products by Multiple Filters

Tags: sorting, shopify

I am trying to sort a collection of products by more than one filter. I want to sort my products by their tag ( `collection.products | sort: 'tags'` ) and by title ascending ( `collection.products | sort: 'title'` ). I have tried multiple variations of the following:

```
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products | sort: 'title' | sort: 'tags' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products | sort: 'tags' | sort: 'title' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products | sort: 'title' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = sortedProducts | sort: 'tags' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products | sort: 'tags' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = sortedProducts | sort: 'title' %}
```

None of them work. I have seen questions with answers that involve filtering by tag and then sorting alphabetically, but I was hoping to sort by tag and title on the same page. If it's not possible, then I'll look more into filtering by tag before sorting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently with liquid tags you shouldn't leave spaces, like below(untested):

```
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products|sort:'title'|sort:'tags' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products|sort:'tags'|sort:'title' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products|sort:'title' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = sortedProducts|sort:'tags' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = collection.products|sort:'tags' %}
{% assign sortedProducts = sortedProducts|sort:'title' %}
```

Then there's one more complication: pagination.
There is a pagination setting somewhere in your settings or theme settings. The default is 50 products per 'page'. The problem in my experience is when you ask it to sort it may only sorting within the first 50 products :(